# Is there a function to generate alternative +1s and -1s for a particular column in a table in Clickhouse database?

Tags: clickhouse

A little bit of background: I have a customer-data-lake which is like a repository having both old and new versions of each customer. I simply have to pick the latest record, but the materialized view will ONLY show the updated records.

My use case: I need the latest record of the updated customer along with other customers.

As a workaround to solve this problem I plan to use `CollapsingMergeTree` for which I have to generate alternatives `+1s` and `-1s` for the `_sign` column. Then the engine will automatically fetch the `+1s` and deletes the records with `-1s`.

In other words I am looking for alternative to `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Instead of consecutive number, I need `+1`, `-1` alternatively.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW crm_customers_mv
to idl_db_crm_customers
 '{replica}') ORDER BY crm_customer_id AS
SELECT *  EXCEPT(Rn)
FROM(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY crm_customer_id ORDER BY `_ingestion_ts` DESC) AS Rn
    FROM idl_db.crm_customers_data_lake)
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Comment: Just curious - any chance of a race condition? That might screw up the logic...that's if you can figure it out! There is no auto-increment feature in ClickHouse (or really anything similar to it). Maybe your client can include that logic?

Comment: Have you tried [ReplacingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree)? If yes, then what's the problem with it in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the ROW_NUMBER() with a modulo function to generate an alternating series of +1s and -1s? This would look like `IF(Rn % 2 = 1, 1, -1)'.